# Pulling associations values with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for the first time and I having trouble getting my head around the association / foreign key relationships when pulling data into my jsons. I have some experience with SQL joins when I used PHP and I want to display the values that relate to the integer values in my diveSchool model.

Is there an easy way to do this without creating a complicated API?

The integers with ID relate to other tables and I have the foreign keys already created in pgadmin. Obviously the integers will mean nothing by themselves when displayed on the front-end.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const diveSchool = sequelize.define("diveSchools", {

        diveSchoolID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        diveSchoolName: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolLocation: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolRegionID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveCertificatesOfferedID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSpotsOfferedID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSchoolGeo: {
            type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
            allowNull: false
        },
        },
        {
            timestamps: false
        }, {});
        diveSchool.associate = function(models){
            diveSchool.belongsTo(models.diveRegion, {foreignKey: 'diveSchoolRegionID', as: 'diveRegion'})
            diveSchool.belongsTo(models.diveCertification, {foreignKey: 'diveCertification', as: 'diveCertification'})
            diveSchool.belongsTo(models.diveSpot, {foreignKey: 'diveSpotID', as: 'diveSpot'})
        };
    return diveSchool;
};
```

diveRegion.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const diveRegion = sequelize.define("diveRegions", {

        diveRegionID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        diveRegion: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        },{});
    diveRegion.associate = function(models){
        diveRegion.hasMany(models.diveSchool, {as: 'diveRegion'})
    };
    return diveRegion;
};
```

diveCertifications.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const diveCertification = sequelize.define("diveCertifications", {

            diveCertificationID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            diveCertificationName: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        },{});
    diveCertification.associate = function(models){
        diveCertification.hasMany(models.diveSchool, {as: 'diveCertificatesOfferedID'})
        diveCertification.hasMany(models.diveCertsCompleted, {as: 'diveCertsCompletedID'})
    };
    return diveCertification;
};
```

diveSchool.controller.js API

```
exports.allDiveSchools = (req, res) => {

    approvedDivingSchool.findAll({})
        .then((approvedDivingSchool) => {

            const diveSchoolsList = [];
            for (i = 0; i < approvedDivingSchool.length; i++) {
                diveSchoolsList.push(approvedDivingSchool[i].dataValues);
            }
            if (!approvedDivingSchool) {
                return res.status(404).send({ message: "No dive schools stored in this region." });
            }

            res.status(200).send({
                data: diveSchoolsList,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out eager loading and how to code associations in the Sequelize docs. Note that I already had associations in the style above in model that didn't work however there are are examples of how to code include statements with the "example1.belongsTo(example2) style and then the include statements inside the 'where' methods in API's.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html